# Installation of R 3.3.1 in Red Hat. LZMA version >=5.0.3 required

Tags: r, redhat, lzma, xz

I am installing R 3.3.1 from source. During `./configure --enable-R-shlib` execution, error pops up:

```
checking for lzma_version_number in -llzma... yes
checking lzma.h usability... yes
checking lzma.h presence... yes
checking for lzma.h... yes
checking if lzma version >= 5.0.3... no
configure: error: "liblzma library and headers are required"
```

I see that there is no LZMA version 5.0.3 available and is currently available through `XZ Utils`.

[Tukaani XZ Utils](http://tukaani.org/xz/)

I installed the `XZ 5.2.2` but the error is still showing up.

Comment: Try to install the `liblzma-devel` package with `yum install liblzma-devel`.

Comment: liblzma-devel is not available

Comment: Used `yum install lzma-devel`? You can also have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185244/cmake-error-could-not-find-liblzma-missing-liblzma-include-dir) and [here](http://pj.freefaculty.org/blog/), point 7.

Comment: Have tried both of them. It isn't working

Comment: @technOslerphile : Please edit your post to include RHEL version : `cat /etc/redhat-release` .... » I installed the XZ 5.2.2 but the error is still showing up « : If installed to /usr/local/ , it's still later in the search path. /usr/ is first, and will be selected as [version].

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and it got fixed after installing xz and xz-devel as `yum install xz xz-devel`.